# Lib import issue: Where is located SUPApplication.h and SUPConnectionProperties.h?

Tags: ios, import, sybase, sup

I'm developing an application to use with SAP's SUP platform.
While importing the generated code, I'm facing a problem.

The code says that can't find the SUPApplication.h and SUPConnectionProperties.h' import.

I've followed all the official Sybase's guide (http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01217.0212/doc/html/jne1320712216435.html) and found some information on Google, but nothing related to this.

Does anyone know to say where, in the libs, this files are located?
All other imports, like SUPDataVault, SUPConnectionProfile and all others SUP_* are fine.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

It was a version problem.
I developped the app in a SUP 2.1.0 and was trying to reach a SUP 2.1.2.

My mistake, thanks